# Close proxy authentication pop-up via Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, automation

I work at a place that blocks social media sites and pops up a proxy log-in for those (few) folks who have legitimate business reasons for going to them.  Since most sites have a Facebook, Twitter or similar link, the proxy prompt comes up quite a bit.  When browsing in a normal, human-driven fashion, I just hit the ESC key to get rid of the proxy log-in dialogue.  How can I do this via Selenium? I've seen alot of posts and solutions for either closing ALERT messages or modal dialogues but I haven't seen anything for *closing* the proxy log-in; just bypassing it by supplying credentials.

Any help/tips would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Specs:
I'm using Selenium 2.44 with the Firefox driver in C#

(**Edit #2:** A little more info on this dialogue)

This log-in prompt is coming from our own internal proxy server.  Our proxy server is basically asking the user if they even have permission to go to the site requested before any communication is made to the remote site.  It pops up any time an element is on the remote site.  So for instance, if a site has a button for Facebook and Twitter which pulls the button from Facebook or Twitter itself, the user will see two proxy log-in prompts.  While the other elements of the page will load as it waits, the page-load process ultimately waits for an answer for any elements that are otherwise automatically blocked.

One way I have gotten around this is to use the Firefox driver in combination with NoScript and remove all social networking links from the white-list.  It's a crude workaround and forces the use of one browser.  What I'm seeking is a way for Selenium to simply close the proxy log-in prompt via code (if that even be done).

(**Edit**: Added screenshot example)
[image]

(**Edit**: Added screenshot from Inspect)
[image: Screenshot from Inspect of proxy window]

Comment: Hello @Jim M, can you please post a screenshot of the 'popup' and also the line of code where you expect to close it so I can provide you with a better answer?

Comment: Hello @TidusJar - Added a screenshot as requested.  I can't ID the lines of code - It happens on any page that has links to sites (for buttons, etc to their site) that our internal policy deems "not business-related".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about selenium but you could use the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace instead.

1. Subscribe to top level window opens
2. Use the `AutomationElement` received to check if it matches your Firefox window information (you can use a took like Inspect to find out what they are)
3. Use the `AutomationElement` above to subscribe to child window opened events
4. On event, check if it is the proxy popup
5. Use the close method on it or SendKeys to send an ESC

Here's a sample code, you will have to gather the classnames, automation ids and names of the windows (feel free to commend and I'll edit the answer):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace FirefoxAutomation
{
    class FirefoxAutomation
    {
        private const string FF_CLASSNAME = "MozillaWindowClass"; //"Firefox ClassName taken from Inspect";
        private const string FF_AUTOMATIONID = null;//"Firefox AutomationId taken from Inspect";
        private static readonly Regex FF_NAME = new Regex("( - Mozilla Firefox)$"); //new Regex("Firefox Name regex based on name taken from Inspect");

        private const string PROXY_CLASSNAME = "MozillaDialogClass";//"Proxy window ClassName taken from Inspect";
        private const string PROXY_AUTOMATIONID = null;//"Proxy window AutomationId taken from Inspect";
        private static readonly Regex PROXY_NAME = new Regex("^(Authentication Required)$");//new Regex("Proxy window Name regex based on name taken from Inspect");

        public FirefoxAutomation()
        {
            SubscribeTopLevelWindowOpened();
        }

        private void SubscribeTopLevelWindowOpened()
        {
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
                AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Children, TopLevelWindowOpened);
        }

        private void TopLevelWindowOpened(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as AutomationElement;
            if (element == null) return;

            // Filter for FireFox window element
            if (!MatchWindow(element, FF_CLASSNAME, FF_AUTOMATIONID, FF_NAME)) return;

            // Subscribe for child window opened even
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
                element, TreeScope.Children, FireFoxChildWindowOpened);
        }

        private void FireFoxChildWindowOpened(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as AutomationElement;
            if (element == null) return;

            // Filter for a proxy message
            if (!MatchWindow(element, PROXY_CLASSNAME, PROXY_AUTOMATIONID, PROXY_NAME)) return;

            // Find the cancel button
            var controls = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition).Cast<AutomationElement>().ToList();
            var cancelButton = controls.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Current.ControlType == ControlType.Button && c.Current.Name == "Cancel");
            if (cancelButton == null) return;

            // Get the click pattern
            object clickPatternObj;
            if (!cancelButton.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out clickPatternObj)) return;
            ((InvokePattern)clickPatternObj).Invoke(); // click the cancel button
        }

        private bool MatchWindow(AutomationElement element, string className, string automationId, Regex name)
        {
            var current = element.Current;
            if (current.ControlType != ControlType.Window) return false;
            if (className != null && current.ClassName != className) return false;
            if (automationId != null && current.AutomationId != automationId) return false;
            if (name != null && name.IsMatch(current.Name)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .@DoronG - I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: -@DoronG - Sorry for the delay. I was on travel for a while.  I haven't tried the above solution but I will when I get a chance. The NoScript trick (mentioned above) does work but isn't a real solution - particularly for those who can't use FireFox

Comment: -@DoronG - Having a little trouble with the implementation - System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElementCollection does not contain a defn for 'ToList' on line [var controls = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition).ToList();]  I'll keep workin' at it.

Comment: @JimM - Add `using System.Linq;` statement to the top

Comment: -@DoronG - using System.Linq; was already there in the code. I've also added references to all UIAutomation collections.  Still no love from the compiler

Comment: @JimM - You're right, was missing a `.Cast<AutomationElement>()`. Fixed above

Comment: -@DoronG - Got a link for "Inspect"?  I'd like to be consistent with what you're using.  (I did look but got alot of hits for "inspector" and the like)

Comment: It is part of the windows SDK.

Comment: -@DoronG - Still working on Inspect.  I found it easily enough (thanks for the tip) but getting things installed here practically takes a Congressional Writ.

Comment: You can just install it on another machine and copy the inspect file

Comment: I'm going to add a screenshot above with Inspect info.  There isn't a classname (that I can see) and did you mean "annotationID" rather than "automationID"?

Comment: @JimM - Your _Inspect_ is configured to `MSAA`, please change it to `UI Automation` in the drop-down on the top left.

Comment: I was able to replicate your popup window, so I went ahead and grabbed the actual binding data. Updated the code above. Please double check if it is not different for your instance.

Comment: Hey @DoronG, I've got the code in and your labels are correct.  It doesn't work, but I'm convinced the problem is my implementation of your solution.  I'm going to give you the (much deserved) credit for the answer and, when time permits, get the code working and post the full solution down the road.  Thanks for all of your help and pointers along the way!!

Comment: Please update if you're not able to get it working. First  troubleshooting steps would be to break in `TopLevelWindowOpened` and `FireFoxChildWindowOpened` see you are getting them.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the website like this:

```
WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://username:password@website.com");
```

The website.com would be the usual website.

If you do not want to log in you can just use an `Action` to send an Escape key to the driver:

```
var action = new Actions(WebDriver);
action.SendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: The authentication request is actually coming from *our* company's proxy server asking if you (the user) have special permission to go to this otherwise blocked site.  I'll report back tomorrow on the esc-key option and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello @TidusJar.  The SendKeys() strategy didn't work.  The dialogue comes up during the initial page-load of the website.  The dialogue actually stops the page-load from continuing until it is closed (which I do manually at the moment).